# Banno and Lease Loans

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We are in the process of doing a Leasing Product on the Symitar core. And one of the things we need to address is, in Banno on a normal loan it shows he Interest Earned and the Interest Rate in the Loan Record.

We are not allowed to reference Interest Earned or Interest Rate for a Lease loan.  Is there anyway to remove this information from certain Loan Types within the Banno app?

I looked at my normal Loan in Banno and it shows Interest Accrued and Rate which on a Lease Loan it can't show

Comment: This question isn't about a feature in the _Banno Digital Toolkit_ but rather about the operations of the Banno product _itself_.

Your best bet is to open a jSource case and ask the question.

Answer (score -1):

This question isn't about a feature in the *Banno Digital Toolkit* but rather about the operations of the Banno product *itself*.

Your best bet is to open a jSource case and ask the question.

Comment: I did and they told me to post it out here!  Gave me a link and everything

Comment: If you mentioned 'software development' or similar, the support team may have been confused and assumed that you needed info about using the Digital Toolkit. My understanding is that you're actually interested in configuring the Banno product itself, so that fits within the domain of the support team. I think if you re-ask the question as purely about configuring Banno, without mentioning development, you should hopefully get routed correctly to someone who can help answer that configuration question.

Comment: FYI Stack Overflow does not provide a Customer Support platform. Also, what you posted isn't an answer - it's general advice on how to get support.